# twitterボタンのカスタマイズ

Tags: laravel, twitter

このように公式のシェアボタンを設置したところ、公式の小さなボタンが表示されます。
（大きさを変えたい。OGP headerに記載済み）

`class="twitter-share-button"`の、`twitter-share-button`にstyleを当てれば、widthなど適応できるのかなと思ったのですが、できないようです。

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large"　data-show-count="false"></a>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

下記のサイトなどを参考にいろいろ試してみたのですが、うまく表示ができません。

`<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">`のコードを入れないと、うまく動かないのではないでしょうか？

[オリジナルのシェアボタンを作ろう！各種SNSのボタン設置用URLまとめ](https://webdesign-trends.net/entry/3632)

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?
  url=<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>&
  via={Twitter ID}&
  related={Twitter ID}&
  hashtags=web,webdesign&
  text=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" 
  rel="nofollow" 
  target="_blank">Tweet</a>
```

※ `url=<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>&`の部分を `url="{{ url()->current()}}"&` としてみましたが、動かず･･･

ちなみに、laravelを使っていまして、idを付与した個別ページtwitterでシェアする形です。

ご存知のかたがいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。